# Setup workspaces and programs in windows

Tags: windows

I'm trying to setup a quick automatic workspace on windows 10 like opening up chrome, vs code, windows terminal in a desktop and position it so as chrome takes half the screen, vs code and terminal stack on each other and share the other half of the screen. I would love to have something like a keyboard shortcut and window would create a new virtual desktop and launching all of those program in customized position.